# entity framework how to define a class within another class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Total newbie to MVC, I have a library application that I built in PHP/MySQL. I'm trying to move it to MVC. I have moved over the database to SQL server, and I'm trying to set up the entity framework.
I have the following classes (each in a separate file):

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public int? SeriesID { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    etc
}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

}
```

If what I understand is true, this should create an instance of a Book object that contains an instance of a Genre object. But when I compile it I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Inner Exception: Invalid column name 'Genre_GenreID'

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? How do I have to set this up properly in order for it to work?

Comment: Add GenreID in Book class ...it serves as foreign key

Comment: @DanHunex This is wrong

Comment: We should know how you configured the associations in Entity Framework

Comment: If you use the convention that is how it works, here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: If the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the other side of the relationship, and add the foreign key for the Genre. I also like to explicitly define my foreign keys.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public int? SeriesID { get; set; }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GenreID")]
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    etc
}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

The reason that entity is looking for `Genre_GenreID` is that you don't have one created for on `Book` and so it is creating one for you.

*Note:* There are conventions set in place and some of the attributes are not needed, or could be placed the other way around, but I feel defining things like this requires little time, and increases future developer code readability.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to define the foreign key in the database as well, or just in the code?

Comment: @MackTheKnife create a migration or yes add the column and foreign key